# AWK in Bash script not working 100% of the time

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am trying to write a bash script that looks for duplicate processes running and prints the PID and  the process name.

Currently the output is correct about 60% of the time. The rest of the time the output prints in the wrong field or does print at all.

The input file is a simple csv file with the name of process to search for ($nam) and the number of lines that should be returned($num).

The script is looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "\n+++++Start++++++\n"
x=0
while [ $x  -lt 1 ]
    do 
        while IFS=, read nam num || [[ -n "$num" ]]; do
            if [ $(pgrep -f $nam | grep -v /bin/bash | grep -v grep | wc -l) -gt $num ]; then 
                echo -e "*********************\n   DUPES? - "$nam" "
                pgrep -lf $nam >| tmpout.txt |  sort -k12 < tmpout.txt | awk '{ print $1" : " $12 }' | sort -k1n -k2 | uniq -f 1 -D  > output.txt 
                cat output.txt
                (( x++ ))
                echo -e "*********************\n"
            else
                (( x++ ))
                echo -e "NO DUPES! - "$nam  
            fi
        done < inputs.txt
done
echo -e "\n++++++END++++++\n"
```

When correct the output should look like this:

```
   +++++Start++++++
*********************
   DUPES? - it1
2509 : it1
3051 : it1
*********************
*********************
   DUPES? - it2
2517 : it2
3261 : it2
*********************
NO DUPES! - floor
++++++END++++++
```

When it does not work correctly the output looks like this:

```
  +++++Start++++++
*********************
   DUPES? - it1
2509 : it1
3051 : it1
*********************
*********************
   DUPES? - it2
*********************
NO DUPES! - floor
++++++END++++++
```

Or like this:

```
  +++++Start++++++
*********************
   DUPES? - it1
2509 : it1
3051 : it1
*********************
*********************
   DUPES? - it2
2509 : it1
3051 : it1
*********************
NO DUPES! - floor
 ++++++END++++++
```

I have tested all pieces individually and they work correctly.

Comment: As the bash tag you added instructs - `For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting here.`. Then update your question with the fixed script and let us know if you still have a problem and make sure to add sample input, not just the output.

Comment: The inputs to the procedure are `inputs.txt` and the entire table of running processes. Since the latter is changing, you might never see the same behavior twice. I mean if `inputs.txt` says to look for at least two copies of `its2`, and `pgrep` doesn't find at least two lines, maybe some `its2` processes simply terminated, so it's telling the truth.